# Changing the name of a system user

Tags: osx, users

Have been using command line for a while with research and my coworkers laugh at my system user name....
[image]

This is my mother's email address... she bought me the computer around 8 years ago but I am certain I was the one setting the machine up...

I'm not familiar enough with how this works, it seems my username should be the one that I login into as opposed to Guest upon turning the machine on.

Any ideas on how to change this that avoid the only suggestion I've got thus far with is creating a new user and copying "everything" over?

If that is indeed the easiest way to remedy this, I may just forget about it and get laughed at, or ask for help with that.

Cheers!

Comment: What Unix is this? macOS?

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text.  Just paste the text, highlight it in the editor, and press `^K` or click the 'format as code' button.

Comment: [Change the name of your macOS user account and home folder](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht201548)

Comment: yes mcOS sorry! ok sorry about the pic! thought it was the best way

Comment: ^^ @MarkPlotnick

Comment: disregard this hasnt been answered yet,

Comment: dyn137083:~ jabennett$ pwd
/Users/boymommy148
dyn137083:~ jabennett$

Comment: looks like terminal header has changed, but user is still not right

Comment: Changing the username doesn't change the home directory's name.

Comment: Thank you both for bearing with me! Sorry I am at work and lazy, didn't read all of the article @MarkPlotnick suggested! Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

Big thank you to Mark Plotnick for this!

macOS Sierra, El Capitan, Yosemite

```
Choose Apple menu () > System Preferences, then click Users & Groups.
Click lock, then enter an administrator name and password. 
From the list of users, Control-click or right-click the user that you want to rename. Choose Advanced Options from the shortcut menu.
Change the name in the “Full name” field, then click OK.
```